# shell script syntax error 'var=$' unexpected

Tags: bash, unix, sh

Can someone explain to me why the following shell script line throws this error:

```
#!/bin/sh
var=$(uptime | awk ' { print $2 } ');
echo $var ;
```

Error:

```
syntax error 'var=$' unexpected
```

Comment: How you are running the script?

Comment: Of course, capturing the output into a variable so you can `echo` that variable is a roundabout approximation of simply not capturing the output, so that it gets printed to standard output.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the system and how it's configured, `/bin/sh` doesn't necessarily understand the `$(...)` syntax. Either change it to the older syntax:

```
var=`uptime | awk ' { print $2 } '`
```

or change the first line to

```
#!/bin/bash
```

(Yes, POSIX specifies the `$(...)` command substitution syntax for `sh`, but `/bin/sh` isn't always POSIX-compliant.)

(Incidentally, the trailing semicolons are not necessary.)

Comment: Thankyou for the tip POSIX compliance @keith-thompson